# how to set Listener when the program is paused (the user get out of the app)?

Tags: android

I have a game app, and I want to pause the game when the user presses Back, Home, Menu, or Power buttons.
I tried the code below but only the back button works. The others don't show even Toast message. I don't know why. Is there any code problem? If not, is there better way to do it?

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
            pause(null);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Hello World",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            pause(null);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Hello World",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            pause(null);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Hello World",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER:
            pause(null);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Hello World",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

}

Comment: This is what the lifecycle methods of an Activity are for.

Comment: Check out the `onPause()` method of the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put your code for pausing the game in `onPause` method of your Activity (in Android studio, you can click `CTRL+O` to get the override method menu, and start typing **onPau** and choose the method):

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    pause(null);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Hello World",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Now if your activity for **whatever** reason gets out of focus (something else is opened on top of it, e.g. open whatsapp to answer a message), it'll get paused. I recommend you read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html).